# Symfony: How to associate the database records in findAll method

Tags: php, symfony

I am learning `symfony 2.7`.

I have two entities `Book` and `Category` under custom bundle and there is a relation between them.

I have CRUD system for `Book` entity.

My issue is..

in `indexAction()` method of `book` controller i want to display category name in listing along with other data.

I tried..

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('CustomBookBundle:Book')->findAll();
    $category_name = $entities->getCategory();
```

But got an error `Call to a member function getCategory() on a non-object`.

I did the same for `showAction` method and it works because there is `find` method which fetch a data for single book.

I want to know how to fetch all associated records for books.

Also how to pass them to `Twig template`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `findAll` , so this will be a collection.

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('CustomBookBundle:Book')->findAll();
```

You can iterate through the `$entities` and call `getCategory()` method if the entity have the method.

```
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    echo $entity->getCategory();
}
```

Comment: How to pass it to `Twig` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('CustomBookBundle:Book')->findAll();
```

I found a very simple answer using `Twig`.

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    .
    .
    <td>{{ entity.getCategory().getName() }}</td>
    .
{% endfor %}
```